# Element-ui NavMenu behaving weird, menu items in the middle instead of the left

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to use this simple [NavMenu](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu#top-bar) but it's doing something weird on where it's placing the menu items.

[image]

This is my code, binding the `href` doesn't make a difference it still displays the same.

```
 <el-menu
        mode="horizontal"
        :unique-opened="true"
        background-color="#96C349"
        text-color="#274F29"
        active-text-color="#274F29">
        <el-menu-item index="1">
            <a :href="'/products'">Productos</a>
        </el-menu-item>
        <el-menu-item index="2">
            <a :href="'/us'">Quienes Somos</a>
        </el-menu-item>
    </el-menu>
```

The most bizarre thing is if I add a second menu under or above it, the menu on the bottom shows the items to the left but when I have only one menu it puts the items like in the middle.

I don't know how or why this is happening! How can I fix it?

Comment: I think some other/own css messing up the layout, could you reproduce the issue in codepen?

Comment: @dreijntjens I just removed everything and copy pasted it from a different page, where it was working and them it worked, I didn't even change anything I don't even know wtf was going on with that. At least it's working now.